# MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 251

Tags: php, laravel

Siempre que intento hacer mi DELETE en laravel me muestra errores, le he movido bastante y aun no encuentro la solución. Espero que alguien me pueda ayudar, soy muy nueva en laravel.

Este es el form de mi DELETE:

```
    <form method="POST" action="{{ url("/eliminar/{$busq->idArma}") }}">
    @csrf
    @method('DELETE')
    <button type="submit">Eliminar</button>
    </form>
    </td>
```

Este es mi Controlador

```
    use App\Armas;
    use DB;

        public function destroy($idArma)
        {
            DB::table('arma')
                ->where('idArma', $idArma)
                ->delete();
                return redirect('/vmearma');
        }
```

Este es mi modelo:

```
    protected $table = 'arma';
    protected $primaryKey = 'idArma';
```

Y mi ruta:

```
Route::delete('/eliminar/{idArma}', "ArmasController@destroy")->name('EArmas');`
```

Comment: Cambia el `method` de `post` a `get`.

Comment: @Shassain me sigue marcando error

Comment: Intenta `url('/eliminar', ['idArma' => $busq->idArma])`

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ `public function read(){ $this->middleware('auth'); $armas=Armas::all(); return view('VMEArmas')->with(compact('armas'));}` un método de lectura

Comment: @CesarRomero Me siguió mostrando error

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ Ya salio muchas gracias, tenias razón era por mi donde la redirija

Comment: Vale, si te parece bien agrega una respuesta explicando la causa del error y cómo lo solucionaste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el controlador le cambie la ruta de mi DELETE:

```
public function destroy($idArma)
{
    DB::table('arma')
        ->where('idArma', $idArma)
        ->delete();
        return redirect('/welcome');


}
```

y en mi form le cambie los `@csrf` y `@method('DELETE')` por `<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">` y `<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">`